# Different NODE_ENV's returns same data but 'different' output

Tags: json, node.js, express

When I run my app with `NODE_ENV=test node app.js`, it returns my JSON like this:

```
[{"title":"Pancakes","description":"The best pancakes!","readyIn":"20 min","method":"To make the best pancakes do this..","_id":"52c1eca507becc63ed000002","ingredients":[{"name":"eggs","amount":"2"},{"name":"plain flour","amount":"100g"},{"name":"milk","amount":"300ml"}]}]
```

When I just run `node app.js` (development environment), I get JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Pancakes",
    "description": "The best pancakes!",
    "readyIn": "20 min",
    "method": "To make the best pancakes do this..",
    "_id": "52c6ab0e696daa0000000002",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "eggs",
        "amount": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "plain flour",
        "amount": "100g"
      },
      {
        "name": "milk",
        "amount": "300ml"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The code for the route doesn't change behaviour in different environments:

`app.get('/recipes', recipe.all);`

```
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Recipe.all(function(err, recipes) {
    if(err) return res.json(500, 'Internal Server Error');
    if(recipes === null) recipes = {};
    return res.json(200, recipes);
  });
};

Recipe.prototype.all = function(callback) {
  RecipeModel.find({}, function(err, recipes) {
    if(err) return(err, null);
    return callback(null, recipes);
  });
};
```

Slightly confused why this is happening. The data is exactly the same, but the way it's getting output is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [(relevant) source code for `express`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/8a7a695836e6c2fe1145ad100a6eaae6235722e4/lib/response.js#L188-L190) and [here, too](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/72daae1d920086b785a822adbda38a803f09e71d/lib/application.js#L85-L87)

- The [pertinent test](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/197a2e3b54260c8003371f29291fca1f545b6c02/test/res.json.js#L97-L127)

That's just how `express` works. `JSON.stringify` calls get prettified if `NODE_ENV` is development (which is the default value if you don't set it, by the way)

```
describe('"json spaces" setting', function(){
  it('should default to 2 in development', function(){
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
    var app = express();
    app.get('json spaces').should.equal(2);
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  })

  it('should be undefined otherwise', function(){
    var app = express();
    assert(undefined === app.get('json spaces'));
  })

  it('should be passed to JSON.stringify()', function(done){
    var app = express();

    app.set('json spaces', 2);

    app.use(function(req, res){
      res.json({ name: 'tobi', age: 2 });
    });

    request(app)
    .get('/')
    .end(function(err, res){
      res.text.should.equal('{\n  "name": "tobi",\n  "age": 2\n}');
      done();
    });
  })
})
```